# How To Redirect to Google Play App [FastAPI]

Tags: fastapi

How can I redirect mobile user directly to Google play application?

Now I am using 
`RedirectResponse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=uz.bringo")`
but it redirects to browser not application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    from user_agents import parse
    ua = parse(request.headers.get('user-agent'))

    if ua.is_mobile:
        if ua.os.family.lower() == 'ios':
            resp = RedirectResponse("https://apps.apple.com/uz/app/bringo/id1470378530")
        else:
            rsp = RedirectResponse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=uz.bringo")
        return resp
```